# C get string with spaces, of unknown length, with fgets

Tags: c, string, space, scanf

I have a file with 1 line in it, on Linux it defaults to end with a newline

```
one two three four
```

And a similar one with

```
one five six four
```

It is guaranteed that the two words in between will never be "four".
I wrote the following, wanting to assign "two three" and "five six" to a variable, as in this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool getwords(FILE *example)
{
    bool result = 0;
    char *words;
        if(fscanf(example, "one %s four\n", words) == 1)
        {
            printf("captured words are %s\n", words);
            if(words == "two three"
            || words == "five six")
            {
                puts("example words found");
            }
            else
            {
                puts("unexpected words found");
            }
            result = 1; //so that we know this succeeded, in some way
        }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    FILE *example;
    example = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    printf("%x\n", getwords(example)); //we want to know the return value, hex is okay
    fclose(example);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that this will print "captured words are " and then only the first word of the two to be expected in a string. This is supposed to support files where there could be more words than 2 in between the words "one" and "four".
How can I change my code, to get all the words in the string between first and last word?

Comment: `words == "two three"` doesn't do what you think. You have to use `strncmp` or other safe comparison functions.

Comment: @Mahesh: `strcmp` is perfectly safe if you know that both arguments point to null-terminated strings.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bunch of errors in your code in its current state.

First, you need to allocate `char *words;`. The statement currently only declares a pointer to a string, and does not *create* the string. A quick fix would be `char words[121];`.

Also, limit the capturing range of scanf to match the length of `words` with `scanf("one %120s four", words);`. But this won't capture the two words, as `%s` searches for only one word. A solution would be to scan each words `fscanf("one %120s %120s four", first_word, second_word);` and then compare the one by one.

Second, you cannot compare two strings using the `==` operator. `==` compares the value of variables, and `words` is simply a pointer. A fix would be to use `strcmp(words, "two three") == 0` where you wrote `words == "two three"`

Comment: That still wont get the separate words. `fscanf` will stop at the space after "two" in "one two three four"

Comment: "%120s" may store 120 scanned characters and then the null byte.  Recommend "%119s".

Comment: Actually, it would be advisable to get rid of `scanf()` completely, and use `fgets()` and `strchr()` instead.

Comment: I second @H2CO3 recommendation on `fgets()`.  The OP's "one %s four\n" hints that a `\n` is expected to terminates the scan, but a `\n` in `fscanf()` matches _any_ whitespace.  If a `scanf()` format ends with `\n`, it is definitely time to switch to `fgets()` which _does_ stop on `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Have taken your code and modified it to work with Eclipse/Microsoft C compiler.  But, overall I think that I have kept your original intentions intact(?).

Please review and notice the minor changes.  I understand that this is probably one of your first programs written in C, so having said that eventually you will learn that non-student programs are NOT written in this style.

Finally, despite what others say, there is NOTHING wrong with `fscan` when it is used as intended.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getwords(FILE *example)
{
    int result = 0;
    char word1[20];  //<< deprecated, learn and use malloc
    char word2[20];  //<< works for first pgm, etc.

    if( fscanf(example, "one %s %s four", word1, word2) == 2)
        {
            printf("captured words are: %s %s\n", word1, word2);

            if ((!strcmp(word1, "two") && !strcmp(word2,"three")) ||
                (!strcmp(word1, "five") && !strcmp(word2, "six")))
            {
                printf("example words found\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("unexpected words found\n");
            }
            result = 1; //so that we know this succeeded, in some way
        }
    return result;
}

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *example;

    if(argc != 2) {exit(0);}

    example = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    // it is a good practice to test example to see if the file was opened

    printf("return value=%x\n", getwords(example)); //we want to know the return value, hex is okay

    fclose(example);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I feel it is necessary to note that this will onyl work reliable for "words" less or equal to 19 in length, or `sizeof(word) - 1`.

Comment: Of course but that consideration is outside the scope of the problem as presented.  This code is along the lines of a new student lab, so many considerations are ignored.